# Extracting Items in an Unbalanced List - BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am scraping real estate data to format into a tabular format. Some properties do not have all of the same details. For instance - a plot of land does not contain information on the number of bedrooms.

```
<div class="srp-item-property-meta">
    <ul class="property-meta list-horizontal list-style-disc list-spaced">
        <li data-label="property-meta-beds"><span class="data-value meta-
        beds">3</span> bd</li>
        <li data-label="property-meta-baths"><span class="data-
        value">1</span> ba</li>
        <li data-label="property-meta-sqft"><span class="data-
        value">1,224</span> sq ft</li>
        <li data-label="property-meta-lotsize"><span class="data-
        value">6,098</span> sq ft lot</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

vs.

```
<div class="srp-item-property-meta">
    <ul class="property-meta list-horizontal list-style-disc list-spaced">
        <li data-label="property-meta-lotsize"><span class="data-
        value">3.1</span> acre lot</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Using BeautifulSoup if I am trying

```
house = {"beds": [], "baths": [], "lotsize": []}

for beds in soup.find_all("li", {"data-label": "property-meta-beds"}):
    house["beds"].append(beds.text)

for lot in soup.find_all("li", {"data-label": "property-meta-lotsize"}):
    house["lotsize"].append(lot.text)
```

I want to combine all of the properties into a dataframe. But when the loop gets to a property that is missing a piece of information, rather than returning NA or NONE or something like that, it just moves on, so my lists end up with different numbers of entities and they don't line up.

Link: https://www.realtor.com/realestateandhomes-search/48198

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could balance your lists as follows:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = "https://www.realtor.com/realestateandhomes-search/48198"
user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:40.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/40.1'
html = requests.get(url, headers={'User-Agent':user_agent}).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

house = {"beds": [], "baths": [], "lotsize": []}

for div in soup.select('div.srp-item-property-meta'):
    for label, tag in [('property-meta-beds', 'beds'), ('property-meta-baths', 'baths'), ('property-meta-lotsize', 'lotsize')]:
        li = div.ul.find('li', {'data-label':label})
        house[tag].append(li.text if li else 'None')

print(house)
```

This would give you `house` containing:

```
{
  'beds': ['3 bd', '3 bd', '3 bd', '3 bd', '3 bd', '3 bd', '2 bd', '2 bd', '3 bd', 'None', 'None', '3 bd', '3 bd', '3 bd', '3 bd'], 
  'baths': ['1+ ba', '1 ba', '2 ba', '1 ba', '1 ba', '2 ba', '2 ba', '2 ba', '1 ba', 'None', 'None', '1 ba', '2 ba', '2 ba', '1+ ba'], 
  'lotsize': ['None', '7,405 sq ft lot', '5,663 sq ft lot', '6,098 sq ft lot', '8,712 sq ft lot', '7,405 sq ft lot', '2,178 sq ft lot', 'None', '7,841 sq ft lot', '2.1 acres lot', '2.24 acres lot', '5,663 sq ft lot', 'None', 'None', '7,405 sq ft lot']
}
```

If a given `data-label` is not found, it appends `None`.

Answer (score 0):

See if adding an if/then helps:

```
house = {"beds": [], "baths": [], "lotsize": []}

for li in soup.find_all("li"):
    if li.has_attr("data-label"):
        label = li.attrs["data-label"]
        if label == "property-meta-beds":
           house["beds"].append(li.text)
        else:
           house["beds"].append("NA")

        if label == "property-meta-baths":
            house["baths"].append(li.text)
        else:
            house["baths"].append("NA")

        if label == "property-meta-lotsize":
           house["lotsize"].append(li.text)
        else:
           house["lotsize"].append("NA")
```

Comment: Actually you may need to back this out a level and get the li alone and then look for the data-label part in order to see if it's null. Can you paste a full example of the HTML or is it confidential?

Comment: [Page Source](view-source:https://www.realtor.com/realestateandhomes-search/48198)

It's not confidential - here is the page source. It looks nicer to just point you here than to copy and paste. Properties start at line 2301.

Comment: OK, I'm sure you can probably clean this up some but I think it will do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

To solve the unbalanced list issue, you can create a list of dictionaries, instead of a dictionary of lists.

Code:

```
r = requests.get('https://www.realtor.com/realestateandhomes-search/48198')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')

houses = []

for prop in soup.find_all('div', class_='srp-item-property-meta'):
    house = {}

    beds = prop.find('span', class_='data-value meta-beds')
    if beds:
        house['beds'] = beds.text

    lot = prop.find('li', {'data-label': 'property-meta-lotsize'})
    if lot:
        house['lotsize'] = lot.span.text

    houses.append(house)

print(houses)
```

Output:

```
[{'beds': '3'},
 {'beds': '3', 'lotsize': '7,405'},
 {'beds': '3', 'lotsize': '5,663'},
 {'beds': '3', 'lotsize': '6,098'},
 {'beds': '3', 'lotsize': '8,712'},
 {'beds': '3', 'lotsize': '7,405'},
 {'beds': '2', 'lotsize': '2,178'},
 {'beds': '2'},
 {'beds': '3', 'lotsize': '7,841'},
 {'lotsize': '2.1'},
 {'lotsize': '2.24'},
 {'beds': '3', 'lotsize': '5,663'},
 {'beds': '3'},
 {'beds': '3'},
 {'beds': '3', 'lotsize': '7,405'}]
```

You use the similar logic to get the other details.